# Javascript Sorting. Allocation fail process out of memory error

Tags: javascript, memory-management, out-of-memory, quicksort

I am getting an error of "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory" on my Javascript code. How could I run this code? I see no flaws in the code, because I was doing exactly the same thing as in Python and it works in Python, but here in Javascript I am getting memory errors. Below is my code.

```
   var sample_arr = [-1, 5, 7, 4, 0, 1, -5]
   function My_Partition(container, first_index, last_index) {
       var x = container[last_index];
       var i = first_index - 1;

       for (var elem = 0; elem < container.length-1; elem++) {
               if (container[elem] <= x) {
               i += 1;
               var temp_1 = container[i];
               container[i] = container[elem];
               container[elem] = temp_1;
           }
       }
       var temp_2 = container[i+1];
       container[i+1] = container[last_index];
       container[last_index] = temp_2;

       return i+1;
   }


   function My_Quick_Sort(container, first_index, last_index) {
       if (first_index < last_index) {
           var mid = My_Partition(container, first_index, last_index);
           My_Quick_Sort(container, first_index, mid-1);
           My_Quick_Sort(container, mid+1, last_index);
       }
   }
   My_Quick_Sort(sample_arr, 0, sample_arr.length-1);
   console.log("Sorted Array:", sample_arr);
```

Basically I am trying to implement a sorting algorithm,
I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this sort?

Comment: I am trying to sort a jumbled array to get a sorted version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty spectacular crash.

So, since this looks like a homework/exercise of some sort, rather than answering the question, let's answer the question behind the question: "How do I figure out how to fix problems like this?" The best way is usually to come up with a theory, and then find a way of testing it.

**Theory 1: Stack overflow**

Usually, if you run out of memory, one obvious guess is stack overflow. To try and test that, lets see if we can set a limit on the number of times the functions get called, and run it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net):

```
   var sample_arr = [-1, 5, 7, 4, 0, 1, -5];
   var stop_running = 0;
   function My_Partition(container, first_index, last_index) {
       if (stop_running++ > 100) return;
       ...
   }


   function My_Quick_Sort(container, first_index, last_index) {
       if (stop_running++ > 100) return;
       ...
   }
   My_Quick_Sort(sample_arr, 0, sample_arr.length-1);
   console.log("Sorted Array:", sample_arr);
```

Oops! This still crashes. Guess it's not a stack overflow, since we limited the number of times we could call our two functions.

**Theory 2: Loop**

Let's try another theory. Perhaps what's happening is an infinite loop. Let's log the loop calls [instead](http://jsfiddle.net/ry2XE/) (click for JSFiddle).

Notice that it's stuck in the loop for over 100 iterations. This is way too many for a simple sort. At this point, you might want to add a console.log call and print out the local variables. Try console.log(elem), or console.log(container.length), or perhaps both.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. I am quite new to Javascript and this kind of error I've never seen. So Javascript cannot handle this sorting? I wonder if I can fix this in Javascript way, since the same code works in many other languages. What am I missing? Could you help? This is not a homework. I am just self-studying. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In Python you're using len() right? Try print() len() in Python, and try console.log() container.length in JavaScript. You're supposed to get the same number, right? Do you?

Comment: Console.log is your friend. Take a look at this version, and look at the console: http://jsfiddle.net/ry2XE/3/

Comment: Oh so much easier to see what is going wrong. But still trying to figure out how to make it right. Thanks a lot!